# controlling the number of digits being displayed c++

Tags: c++

I want to display the values (in hex) of these certain registers and counters but I want to limit the number of digits being displayed.

```
cout << "Acc register : " << hex << Acc << ",";      //display 2 digits
cout << " X register : " << hex << X << ",";         //display 3 digits
cout << " Program counter : " << hex << PC << ",";   //display 3 digits
```

I also want to display preceding zeros if the value was only 1 digit long, for example if
`program counter = 4`

`PC` should display as `Program counter : 004`

I have searched the internet to try and find a solution but I can not seem to find something that works.  Can anybody explain how to do this please. Many thanks.

Comment: use `setw()` and `fill('0')`.

Comment: Why not using `printf`? The C++ `cout` and etc. is a pain...

Answer (score 0):

The STL comes with a header called iomanip, which can modify in the way you want and even more.

A short example would be:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setfill ('x');
    std::cout << "PC" << std::setw(3) << 4 << std::endl;
}
```

An additional example can be found here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/

An overview over all options here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried to set the width as per your suggestion but it still displays 4 digits, does it make a difference that the value I am trying to display is in hexadecimal? @OutOfBound

Comment: Probably. Can you post the full code in the question, then i can look for the problem